# Is there a way to avoid huge verbosity when SELECTing with GROUP BY in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query where I `SELECT` many columns (like, 50) and then I want to `LEFT JOIN` this subquery onto another table, `GROUP BY` a unique ID in the first query, pull out an aggregate from the second query, and select all the original columns along with the aggregate.  A small example would be something like:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.value1,
    t1.value2,
    t1.value3,
    t1.value4,
    t1.value5,
    STRING_AGG(t2.joinedValue, ',')
FROM
    MyTable t1 LEFT JOIN AnotherTable t2 ON t1.id = t2.myTableId
GROUP BY
    t1.id
```

The trouble is that the only 2 ways I know of making this work are either to wrap all the `t1` values in a `MIN()` function (or similar), or include all the `t1` values in the `GROUP BY` clause.  Both of these methods are very verbose and also require annoying maintenance whenever the `SELECT` list changes.

Is there a way that I can just tell SQL to select one of the values at random without using some aggregate clause?  I've never understood why an aggregate clause is needed.  When you're doing a `LEFT JOIN` and grouping by the first table's PK, the columns from the left table are all guaranteed to be duplicates anyway so why should you need to explicitly tell your DBMS to "pick the first one" if they're all the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your query *is* valid, standard SQL -- assuming `id` is the primary key of `table1`.  But, SQL Server does not support functional dependencies in the aggregation queries.

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT t1.*,
       (SELECT STRING_AGG(t2.joinedValue)
        FROM AnotherTable t2 
        WHERE t1.id = t2.myTableId
       ) 
FROM MyTable t1;
```

If you have multiple aggregations, you can use `APPLY`:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*            
FROM MyTable t1 CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT STRING_AGG(t2.joinedValue) as strings, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM AnotherTable t2 
      WHERE t1.id = t2.myTableId
     ) t2;
```

These often have better performance than the version with the `GROUP BY` in the outer query as well.